# Why does read.zoo work on this data frame but not on another similar data frame? (index has bad entry)

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo, dplyr

Consider the following script:

```
#tmp is some data frame extracted via dplyr:
#       Time    Open
# 2000-01-10 1.26545
# 2000-01-11 1.25107
# 2000-01-12 1.25177
# 2000-01-13 1.26174
# 2000-01-14 1.26354
# 2000-01-15 1.27431
tmp 

#create another data frame that is similar to tmp
dat <- data.frame(Time = paste("2000-01-", 10:15, sep = ""), Open = tmp$Open)
```

So,

```
> #check that all entries in both data frame are equal to each other
> dat == tmp
     Time Open
[1,] TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE
[4,] TRUE TRUE
[5,] TRUE TRUE
[6,] TRUE TRUE
> #this works
> read.zoo(dat)
2000-01-10 2000-01-11 2000-01-12 2000-01-13 2000-01-14 2000-01-15 
   1.26545    1.25107    1.25177    1.26174    1.26354    1.27431 
> #but this gives an error
> read.zoo(tmp)
Error in read.zoo(tmp) : index has bad entry at data row 1
In addition: Warning message:
drop ignored
```

Why does read.zoo(tmp) give an error while read.zoo(dat) does not, even though both data frames are essentially the same?

The only difference between these two data frames are their classes:

```
> class(dat)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(tmp)
[1] "tbl_df"     "data.frame"
```

But the difference shouldn't matter as both are still a data.frame object, right? What is causing the error on read.zoo(tmp) and how do I fix it?

EDIT:

The output of dput(tmp) is:

```
> dput(tmp)
structure(list(Time = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2000-01-10", 
"2000-01-11", "2000-01-12", "2000-01-13", "2000-01-14", "2000-01-15"
), class = "factor"), Open = c(1.26545, 1.25107, 1.25177, 1.26174, 
1.26354, 1.27431)), .Names = c("Time", "Open"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. `read.zoo(tmp)` works fine for me even when I add the `tbl_df` class.

Comment: @RichardScriven oh no...what else can I do? I've removed and reinstalled zoo and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `dput(tmp)`

Comment: `tbl_df` seems to ignore `drop` argument.

Comment: @GSee The version of dplyr I have is 0.3.0.1, which was packaged on 2014-10-06. What version are you using?

Comment: I was using 0.2, but I updated to 0.3.0.9 and now I _can_ reproduce.

Comment: Why are you using `read.zoo`? I would have expected `as.zoo` or just `zoo` to be used on an object already in the workspace. I think the question should be: "why does it even succeed on a data.frame".

Comment: @Arun is right. `[.tbl_df` doesn't allow `drop=` to be TRUE.  I think you should file a bug report.  For now you can use `read.zoo(as.data.frame(tmp))`

Comment: @GSee okay, I'll go file a bug report. thanks for your help

Comment: @BondedDust I am using `read.zoo` because that was how the vignette did not. Also, I needed to use the strip parameter in `read.zoo` and it looks like `as.zoo` does not support it. I am open to other suggestions...

Comment: I see I don't really understand the `zoo`-package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why zoo can't handle the class tbl_df, per https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/686. Try to coerce using `as.data.frame()`. This was successful for me:

```
tmp %>% #class "tbl_df" and "data.frame"
as.data.frame %>%
read.zoo
```